# IPython notebook widgets using interactive

Tags: widget, ipython, interactive

I'm having trouble creating widgets in a Jupyter notebook that update when other widget values are changed. This is the code I've been playing around with:

```
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

def func(arg1,arg2):
    print arg1
    print arg2

choice = widgets.ToggleButtons(description='Choice:',options=['A','B'])
display(choice)

metric = widgets.Dropdown(options=['mercury','venus','earth'],description='Planets:')
text = widgets.Text(description='Text:')

a = interactive(func,
     arg1=metric,
     arg2=text,
     __manual=True)

def update(*args):
    if choice.value == 'A':
        metric = widgets.Dropdown(options=['mercury','venus','earth'],description='Planets:')
        text = widgets.Text(description='Text:')
        a.children = (metric,text)

    else:
        metric = widgets.Dropdown(options=['monday','tuesday','wednesday'],description='Days:')
        text2 = widgets.Textarea(description='Text2:')
        a.children = (metric,text2)

choice.observe(update,'value')
display(a)
```

The resulting widgets `metric` and `text` do change based whether `A` or `B` is selected, but the problem is that the "Run func" button goes away as soon as I change to `B`. I've tried adding the `__manual` attribute immediately before `display(a)`, adding it within `update`, and several other places. How do I change the children of the widget box without overwriting the fact that I want to manually run the function?